# How to add a button at Page tab ribbon when add webpart?

Tags: 2010, web-part, ribbon, custom-actions

I have a webpart with custom setting.

I add 2 property to webpart setting. I want add button to Page tab ribbon when webpart added to page and value set for the property.

It is possible that add a button to Page tab ribbon?

Comment: Yes, you can add a button to page tab ribbon when you add your web part.For this you need to implement your Ribbon Button as a seperate feature and enable it, and in `Enabledscript` property of your ribbon element you can check if your web part is on the page you can enable the ribbon button.A starting point can be `http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-document-sets-custom-ribbon-buttons-with-custom-code`

Comment: Thanks a lot. but this link not found.

Comment: http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-document-sets-custom-ribbon-buttons-with-custom-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Ribbon Tab which shows up when your web part is selected, this is what is called a Contextual Tab.

MSDN has an article: [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Web Part with a Contextual Tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407578.aspx)

It's a lot of work, but as Wictor Wilén writes in [CKSDev version 2.0 is released - includes Contextual Web Part SPI](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/CKSDev-version-20-is-released-includes-Contextual-Web-Part-SPI.aspx) it's been made a lot easier by [CKSDev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Nice info! But I think he wants to add the button to the already existing "Page" tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use this but i have a problem: when i edit js file and deploy, it is run first js file and don't show changed!

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I understand that you want to add the button to the Page Tab in the Ribbon  whenever a particular WebPart is added to the page.

You can do this with the JavaScript Client Object Model:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185004

Here is a list of all Locations where the Button can be added:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730

If you want to go the Server Side way, you can add the Ribbon button like this:
http://sp365.co.uk/2011/09/programmatically-add-ribbon-custom-action-to-an-existing-list/

Also, I would like to mention that there is an awesome Library on Codeplex for adding ribbon buttons:
http://spribbon.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use Library, but How can I get access to the controls within the web part?

Comment: You can get access to the code from the webpart by the Ribbon Objects provided in the JS Client Object Model as well as the Server Side (C#) code. Check out the examples in the links.

Comment: I have a SpGridView in webpart. I want whne select a row of SpGridView change the link on ribbon.